# 404 error in Flask

Tags: python, flask

There are a number of questions about this, but I have spent the past 7 hours trying everything that's written up here on SO, and I am still getting a 404 error in Flask when trying to render the most basic index.html.

Edited: I stripped my code down and am still getting a 404.  COde reflects newest version...

My code:

**init**.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import basedir

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import views, models
```

Models.py

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, scoped_session


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///bikes.db', convert_unicode=True)

session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = session.query_property()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__="user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(15))
    email = db.Column(db.String(25))
    age= db.Column(db.Integer)

def main():
    Base.metadata.create_all(ENGINE)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

views.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session
from app.models import session as db_session
from app import app, db

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried running just the module that has the @app.route('/')? Why not start small and build on top of that?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian you typed faster than me. Start small, and build on top of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define your routes on the same flask app that you eventually call `.run` on.

Move the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block from views.py to __init.py__.  Remove the `app = Flask(__name__)` line from views.py.