# Can't serve swagger on remotely hosted server with different url

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, swagger

I'm trying to serve some simple service using `flask` and `flask_restx` (a forked project of `flask-restplus`, that would be eventually served on AWS.

When it is served, I want to generate swagger page for others to test it easily.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restx import Api
from my_service import service_namespace

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, version='1.0')
api.add_namespace(service_namespace)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I test it locally (e.g. `localhost:5000`), it works just fine. Problem is, when it is hosted on AWS, because it has a specific domain (gets redirected?) (e.g. *my-company.com/chris-service* to a container), the document page is unable to find its required files like `css` and so:

[image]

#### What I've looked and tried

[Python (Flask + Swagger) Flasgger throwing 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680405/python-flask-swagger-flasgger-throwing-404-error)

[flask python creating swagger document error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081930/flask-python-creating-swagger-document-error)

[404 error in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612775/404-error-in-flask)

Also tried adding `Blueprint` (albeit without knowing exactly what it does):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
blueprint = Blueprint("api", __name__, 
                      root_path="/chris-service",
                      # url_prefix="/chris-service", # doesn't work
)
api = Api(blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
...
```

And still no luck.

### Update

So here's more information as per the comments (pseudo, but technically identical)

1. Access point for the swagger is `my-company.com/chris` (with or without http:// or https:// doesn't make difference)
2. When connecting to the above address, the request URL for the assets are `my-company.com/swaggerui/swagger-ui.css`
3. You **can** access the asset in `my-company.com/chris/swaggerui/swagger-ui.css`
4. So I my resolution (which didn't work) was to somehow change the `root_path` (not even sure if it's the correct wording), as shown in *What I've looked and tried*.

I've spent about a week to solve this but can't find a way.

Any help will be greatful :) Thanks

Comment: Could you share what happens in the service and your repository layout?

Comment: what is a full URL in browser address box and full URL in request header of `404` resource? Is domain name the same? what are both URL paths?

Comment: We can clearly see that only static contents are not accessible. Here is may be hundreds reasons why it happens starting from non deployed (copied) static files and ending with what storage did you set for static files and how did you set routing for it (is it accessing by full path stating from `https://...` or just by URL path starting from `/static/droid-sans.css`) etc etc etc. Here is not enough information

Comment: Also looks like you using developer server for access service at `localhost:5000`. If you using another way to run app in production (for example `gunicorn` app server) then static files handling and behavior may be different

Comment: @rzlvmp I've updated some more info. Please do let me know if you need any more info

Comment: @Chris Ok, if I understand correctly if you insert `https://my-company.com/chris/swaggerui/swagger-ui.css` into browser address bar it is accessible. In this case what is a bad `Request URL` of 404 's resource? ([how to check Request URL in request headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4423097))

Comment: It's one without `chris` in between: `my-company.com/swaggerui/swagger-ui.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger parameters defined at [`apidoc.py`](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/blob/master/flask_restx/apidoc.py) file. Default `apidoc` object also created in this file. So if you want to customize it you have change it before `app` and `api` initialization.

In your case `url_prefix` should be changed (I recommend to use environment variables to be able set `url_prefix` flexibly):

```bash
$ export URL_PREFIX='/chris'
```

```py
from os import environ
from flask import Flask
from flask_restx import Api, apidoc

if (url_prefix := environ.get('URL_PREFIX', None)) is not None:
    apidoc.apidoc.url_prefix = url_prefix

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: It did not work :( But thank you for the answer

Comment: What is `404`'s URL after changing root path?

Comment: Still the same. Note that what I have an issue is with the swagger, not the main api (it works fine). I think I need to change something with the `api` but can't figure out what.

Comment: @Chris sorry for unverified answer. I updated it. Now should work

Comment: I tried, the request url is changed as desired, but the asset has also been moved to `my-company.com/chris/chris/swaggerui/swagger-ui.css` (see the dup in url) but looks like this is where I should be changing and testing. Let me give them a try

Answer (score 1):

Always very frustrating when stuff is working locally but not when deployed to AWS. Reading [this](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/issues/188) github issue, these 404 errors on swagger assets are probably caused by:

1. Missing javascript swagger packages

Probably not the case, since flask-restx does this for you. And running it locally should also not work in this case.

2. Missing gunicorn settings

> Make sure that you are also setting gunicorn up correctly as well with
> --forwarded-allow-ips if deploying with it (you should be)￼. If you are in a kubernetes cluster you can set this to *
>
> https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#forwarded-allow-ips

3. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51698485/get-404-when-running-flask-restplus-app-on-amazon-ec2) post, you also have to explicitly set
   `settings.FLASK_SERVER_NAME` to something like `http://ec2-10-221-200-56.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000`
4. If that does not work, try to deploy a flask-restx [example](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html), that should definetely work. This rules out any errors on your end.

Comment: It did not work :( But thank you for the answer

Comment: Could you tell me how exactly in aws it is hosted an if there are any redirects or rewrites? Maybe post an url so i can check.

Comment: It's hosted via ECS. AP of the service is `api.my-company.com/chris-service` (pseudo address. I'm not allowed to share the actual url :( ), which gets redirected to the container, where it is served `0.0.0.0:5000`. The `ProxyFix` looks promising, let me try.

Comment: The third option could be primising. Binding to 0.0.0.0 works locally, but could give problems in ecs.

Comment: Please let me know if this worked for you. If so mark it as the solution to your problem.